# Footer Content Is Being Pushed When Resizing Window

Tags: html, css

I have something that I don't really understand how to fix. I have a sticky footer on the bottom of my page.

Here's my CSS:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:50px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 102px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('images/footer.png');
    font-size: 15px;
}

.left{
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: Comfortaa-Light;
}
.center{
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: Comfortaa-Light;
}
.right{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-color: black;
    background-image: url('images/main-back.png');
    width: 250px;
    float:right;
    text-align:left;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    font-family: Comfortaa-light;
}
```

I have the footer itself, plus some columns. Now, here's my HTML:

```
         <footer>
        <p class="left"><span class="fb-icon"><a class="footer" href="testimonials.html">Facebook</a></span><br /><span class="craigs-icon"><a class="footer" href="experience.html">Craigslist</a></span></p>
        <p class="right"><span class="phone-icon">Phone:</span> <b>(541) 420 3375</b><br/><span class="mail-icon">E-mail:</span> <a href="mailto:CompLife@gmx.com">CompLife@gmx.com</a></p>
        <p class="center"><span class="testimonial-icon"><a class="footer" href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></span><br /><span class="chatbox-icon"><a class="footer" href="contact.html">Chatbox</a></span></p>
     </footer>
```

Now, whenever I resize my window the footer content starts getting pushed to the left, or to the right, depending on which way I resize the window from. I do not want this to happen, I want the window to resize and leave the footer in place. Could someone please help me?[image: When the window is NOT resized]

[image: When window IS resized]

Comment: You mean you want to keep the width of the footer so if you resize the window it stays out of sight instead of reordering?

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right

Comment: Then you should't set the `width: 100%;` on the footer, that will make it resize with the window. However I would suggest to leave the `width: 100%;` and add a `min-width` css rule with the min  width in pixels that doesn't make the center `p` to move down.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Okay, I've added a min-width rule. And it seems to have fixed, but the actual footer doesn't stretch to 100% of the screen when the page is resized. Not that it's a big deal.

Comment: I will post it as an answer, it may help anyone else. And did it stretch to the whole page before the min-width rule?

Comment: Yes it always stretched to the other side of the page. Only when i resize the window the footer stops stretching to the other side of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the rule `width: 100%;` on the footer you are making it resize with the window, changing the width to a fixed value would fix the problem, however it would make the footer stay out of sight even when it is not necessary so I would suggest to leave the `width: 100%;` and add a `min-width` css rule with the min width in pixels that doesn't make the center p to move down.